# Sending res to client before finishing async processes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have the following code that I can´t figure out how to make this entire process finish before sending a response back to the client. It has a for loop and make the requests to 2 external functions.

The problem that I can see in the console is the response which goes way faster than the process takes to complete the processing. It makes the client believe everything is fine, but, actually some error might has happened. I´ve tried to await, I´ve tried reading other posts, I´ve tried making this to return a promise and return a resolve, I´ve tried an index to check the array length... If someone could help me out, I would appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

```
var updateProdCharTree = async (req, res, next) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var data = req.body.raw.data;
var productLine = req.body.raw.productLine;
var bu = req.body.raw.bu;
let contErros = null;
let contAcertos = 0;

var maxId = 0;
let queryMaxId = `SELECT max(ProductCharFatherId) as maxId FROM maxiplastmatriz.productchar1 WHERE bu=${bu} and prodline=${productLine}`;
database.query(queryMaxId)
  .then(resultqueryMaxId => {
    if(resultqueryMaxId.length){
      maxId = resultqueryMaxId[0]['maxId'];
    }else{
      maxId = 0;
    }

    let queryAllNodes = `SELECT Id FROM productchar1 WHERE bu=${bu} and prodline=${productLine}`;
    database.query(queryAllNodes)
      .then( async resultqueryAllNodes => {

        for (let index = 0; index < data.children.length; index++) {
          const element = data.children[index];
          if (data.children[index].dbId != undefined) {
            let query = `SELECT Id FROM productchar1 WHERE bu=${bu} and prodline=${productLine} and Id=${data.children[index].dbId} and ProductCharFatherId=${data.children[index].id}`;
            database.query(query)
            .then( async result => {
                
              if (result.length) { // Update char in productchar1
                maxId++;
                var params = {element: element, productLine: productLine, bu: bu, index: index};
                waitResUp = await updateProductChar1(params, req, res); //***CALL EXTERNAL METHOD 2***
                contAcertos++;
              } else { // Add char in productchar1 shouldn´t get in here
                    console.log("Erro em: updateProdCharTree > addProductProductChar1");
                }
            
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Erro em query");
                contErros = 1;
            })
      
          }else{ // Add new char in productchar1
            maxId++;
            var params = {element: element, productLine: productLine, bu: bu, index: index, maxId: maxId};
            waitRes = await addProductProductChar1(params, req, res); //***CALL EXTERNAL METHOD 2***
            console.log("waitRes", waitRes.insertId);
            contAcertos++;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Erro em queryAllNodes", err);
        contErros = 1;
      })

  })    
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Erro em queryMaxId");
    contErros = 1;
  });

  if (contAcertos == data.children.length) {
    resolve("result"); // ***RES ATTEMPT***
  }

 })
 }
```

Beginner here. Please be pacient. You were once either.

Comment: Avoid this callback hell by awaiting your DB calls : `const resultqueryMaxId = await database.query(queryMaxId);` Your code will become _much_ clearer and you'll understand way better what's going on.

Comment: Also, if you launch 10 `Promise.then()` inside a `for` loop, all the queries are launched simultaneously, which is heavy, and you can't guarantee the resolution order. By using `await database.query()` you will perform each request in order, one by one.

Comment: But I am using await, right? Besides, I don't really mind about their order. I just wanna make sure everything is processed before I send a response to client.

Comment: Obviously you're not (not everywhere), there are many `database.query().then()` arranged in a nice callback hell. If you don't mind about the resolution order, you can `await Promise.all()` of them together.

Comment: Right. But what do you recommend me to do? Even if I remove the "queryMaxId" query. I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Ok, took me a while to get everything you did there. I also had to understand what I was doing wrong, get the idea behind await Promise.all(), .map, callback hell and make the response get to the client. Thank you very much @Jeremy Thille and Raeesaa for your time and effort. I´m struggling to create a whole system on my own if this kind of help gives me hope. I wish you guys all the best.

Comment: Ha, you're welcome, every one of us went thtough this and has to struggle this much too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you can refactor your code to something like below so that response is returned after all async functions within loop are executed:

```
var updateProdCharTree = async (req, res, next) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var data = req.body.raw.data;
    var productLine = req.body.raw.productLine;
    var bu = req.body.raw.bu;
    let contErros = null;
    let contAcertos = 0;

    var maxId = 0;
    let queryMaxId = `SELECT max(ProductCharFatherId) as maxId FROM maxiplastmatriz.productchar1 WHERE bu=${bu} and prodline=${productLine}`;
    database
      .query(queryMaxId)
      .then((resultqueryMaxId) => {
        if (resultqueryMaxId.length) {
          maxId = resultqueryMaxId[0]["maxId"];
        } else {
          maxId = 0;
        }

        let queryAllNodes = `SELECT Id FROM productchar1 WHERE bu=${bu} and prodline=${productLine}`;
        database
          .query(queryAllNodes)
          .then(async (resultqueryAllNodes) => {
            return Promise.all(
              data.chilren.map(async (element) => {
                if (data.children[index].dbId != undefined) {
                  let query = `SELECT Id FROM productchar1 WHERE bu=${bu} and prodline=${productLine} and Id=${data.children[index].dbId} and ProductCharFatherId=${data.children[index].id}`;
                  let result = await database.query(query);

                  if (result.length) {
                    // Update char in productchar1
                    maxId++;
                    var params = {
                      element: element,
                      productLine: productLine,
                      bu: bu,
                      index: index,
                    };
                    waitResUp = await updateProductChar1(params, req, res); //***CALL EXTERNAL METHOD 2***
                    contAcertos++;
                  } else {
                    // Add char in productchar1 shouldn´t get in here
                    console.log(
                      "Erro em: updateProdCharTree > addProductProductChar1"
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  // Add new char in productchar1
                  maxId++;
                  var params = {
                    element: element,
                    productLine: productLine,
                    bu: bu,
                    index: index,
                    maxId: maxId,
                  };
                  waitRes = await addProductProductChar1(params, req, res); //***CALL EXTERNAL METHOD 2***
                  console.log("waitRes", waitRes.insertId);
                  contAcertos++;
                }
              })
            );
          })
          .then(() => {
            // This will be called after all queries are executed
            resolve("result");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Erro em queryAllNodes", err);
            contErros = 1;
            // NOTE: Ideally we should be rejecting promise in case of error
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Erro em queryMaxId");
        contErros = 1;
        // NOTE: Ideally we should be rejecting promise in case of error
      });
  });
};
```

As @Jeremy Thille suggested this code can be improvised further to only use async-await instead of Promises with `then` callback so that it is more cleaner and easy to understand.

Comment: Ok, took me a while to get everything you did there. I also had to understand what I was doing wrong, get the idea behind await Promise.all(), .map, callback hell and make the response get to the client. Thank you very much Jeremy Thille and @Raeesaa for your time and effort. I´m struggling to create a whole system on my own if this kind of help gives me hope. I wish you guys all the best.

Comment: Good to know this helped :) I would suggest reading more about asynchronous functions in JS and ways of handling them (callbacks, promises, async-await). You will get comfortable with patterns as you write code. It would be great if you mark this question as accepted if it worked for you.